# Transparent SwapChainPanel (compositeMode) - no opaque DirectX drawing?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, directx, uwp

I'm making an Augmented Reality App (C++) in Windows 10 (universal Windows app / WinRT) with openCV.

**Problem:**

I want to have a transparent SwapChainPanel background to make the content behind (webcam stream) visible, but with opaque 3D-models (eg. a cone).

**Try:**

To my research it seems, that setting the CompositeMode of the SwapChainPanel to "minBlend" should do it - yes, but I still want my 3D Objects to be opaque. In fact, I want my objects to be semitransparent, but **always visible**. The "minBlend" mode is more for text-highlighting, not really to overlay something with semitransparent models (dark areas are not overlayed, see pictures).

[Image: Standard DirectX Cube (oqaque background and model)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj2bU.png)

[Image: DirectX Cube overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiFTh.png)

Do you have any suggestions? Is it possible?

**Background:**

I'm making an Augmented Reality Windows 10 App with openCV. For getting the current pixel data of my webcam stream I'm using the Win10 methods **mediaCapture->GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoframe)** with **SoftwareBitmap->LockBuffer** to get access to the bytes in the memorybuffer. The bytes are processed within openCV functions and after processing is complete, I'm setting up a WriteableBitmap to show the modified webcam-stream in my Xaml-UI element. Because of already having classes to draw my DirectX objects and modify them with touch input, i want to use DirectX to overlay the webcam preview with my objects.

*Sorry for not linking the used methods and the linked Images, I haven't enough reputation*

**Edit:** Maybe an alternative would be to create a texture from my pixel data and set up a fullscreen rectangle on my swapchainpanel which functions as a background. Then every frame I have to update the texture data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some official Windows Store examples, changing the compositeMode is the only solution to make Xaml content behind a swapChainPanel visible.

But this workaround finally works: I've created a Texture2D and update the containing data every frame:

```
/*----- Update background texture with new videoframe -----*/

// image = openCV cv::Mat containing the pixeldata of the current frame
if (image.data != nullptr)  
{
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));

    //  Disable GPU access to data.
    auto m_d3dContext = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    m_d3dContext->Map(m_pTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    //  Update texture
    memcpy(mappedResource.pData, image.data, 4*image.rows*image.cols);
    //  Reenable GPU access to data.
    m_d3dContext->Unmap(m_pTexture, 0);
}
```

At first I'm drawing a fullscreen rectangle (SpriteBatch with DirectXTK) with this texture. After that I can draw anything else.